# nvim command not found, but works fine

Tags: bash, command

So I'm trying to have `nvim` as my default editor in `ranger` and I'm about at wits end.

To do this according to their wiki, I just need to `export EDITOR=nvim`. But it just comes up with a `nvim command not found` error. See the seemingly insanity below:

```
[username@login001 clusterUtils]$ export EDITOR=nvim
[username@login001 clusterUtils]$ $EDITOR
bash: nvim: command not found
[username@login001 clusterUtils]$ nvim
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (2.7.1+ or 3.4+) support.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
[username@login001 clusterUtils]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/ibutils/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/home/username/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/home/username/bin:/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/home/username/bin:/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim:/home/username/bin:/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim
[username@login001 clusterUtils]$
```

As you can see, nvim is in my `$PATH` multiple times due to me having put it in `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, and `.bashrc`.

From above, you can see that when I just try to run `$EDITOR`, it comes up with`bash: nvim: command not found`.

However, if I try to open a text file through `ranger`, I get `/bin/sh: nvim: command not found` instead.

I know there are similar questions already posted, but none of their solutions helped me.

---

Edit: Something of note is that this work is being done on a cluster. So I don't have access to the root directory, only my home directory.

Comment: Adding it to your path and environment doesn’t make it installed. Is it?

Comment: What does `which nvim` show for the file path? Does setting `EDITOR` to the absolute path change anything? Does `alias` have anything?

Comment: @ErikF So running `which nvim` made me realize that I forgot to delete an alias for `nvim` that I had previously used in `.bashrc` that I had previously unaliased before. 

Unaliasing that, `which nvim` comes up with `/usr/bin/which: no nvim in [proceeds to list $PATH]`. Note that `/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfv-root/usr/bin/nvim` is in `$PATH`. After the unaliasing, `nvim` now doesn't work normally.

Comment: @ErikF Doing `export EDITOR=/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfv-root/usr/bin/nvim` does work now! As does simply typing in `/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfv-root/usr/bin/nvim`. Any ideas as to why it isn't reading `nvim` from `$PATH` though?

Comment: @JeffSchaller TBH, I don't really know what "installed" means other than there are binaries and they run successfully. The main issue right now is that bash doesn't seem to recognize that it has `nvim` in the `$PATH`. Is there something I'm missing to finish an install for a program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in one of the comments, you seemed to have an alias set, that's why calling `nvim` directly on the shell was working.

After unaliasing it, you no longer can work with `nvim`. The issue you're having there seems to be that your `$PATH` is set incorrectly. You seem to have `/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim` in your `$PATH`, but that's the **full path to the `nvim` binary itself** and not the path to the directory where it's located... `$PATH` only takes directories, not files itself. In this case, the system is trying to find it on `/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim/nvim` which is clearly invalid...

You can correct that by addin `/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfs-root/usr/bin` instead of the incorrect path to your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: That's it. I added `/home/username/bin/neovim/squashfs-root/usr/bin` to `$PATH` and that worked. I was working under the Windows logic of `PATH` environment variables where you can point to a specific file, not just a directory.